# A Python program which finds out the version of Python in my computer

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a Python program which finds out the version of Python that I am using in my computer.

I tried with print() but there is no keyword in vs code that shows me anything about the version of python.

Should I implement a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I am aware of getting this information is through the system library. Hope this helps :)

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```